# Adding a shaded region between two curves on a PGFPLOTS graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween

Ok,

Say we have a graph defined as

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle
    ]
    \addplot[black,domain=-pi/2:pi/2]{cos(deg(x))};
    \addplot[red,domain=-pi/2:pi/2]{1/64*pi^4-1/4*x^4};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

This outputs the following:

[image: Diagram without shading]

Which is exactly what the 2 curves should look like, I now want to create a filled vertical region between these two curves and label it, like so

[image: Ideal diagram!]

What's the best way to achieve this effect? I've figured out the following with assistance of comment on this:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle
    ]
    \addplot[name path=A,black,domain=-pi/2:pi/2]{cos(deg(x))};
    \addplot[name path=B, red,domain=-pi/2:pi/2]{1/64*pi^4-1/4*x^4};
    \addplot[color=black,fill=pink,fill opacity=0.4]fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=-1:-0.5}];
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image: Almost complete diagram]

How do I put a border on the fill?

Comment: @JouleV I've update the question to ask another bit relating to what I've found.

Answer (score 4):

JouleV already gave you the crucial hint. The rest is adding patterns, two vertical lines, and a node.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=1/64*pi^4-pow(\x,4)/4;}]
    \begin{axis}[ymax=1.6,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle
    ]
    \addplot[black,domain=-pi/2:pi/2,name path=A]{cos(deg(x))};
    \addplot[red,domain=-pi/2:pi/2,name path=B]{f(x)};
    \addplot [pattern=north east lines,pattern color=red] fill between [
        of=A and B,soft clip={domain=-1.1:-1},
    ];
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-1.1,-1}{%
    \draw[red] (#1,{cos(deg(#1))}) -- (#1,{f(#1)});}
    \draw[red] (-1.05,{cos(deg(-1.05))})
     -- (-0.95,{cos(deg(-1.05))-0.1}) node[right,draw,text=black]{label};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]